# Cannot call Oracle SP inside a package using nhibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

Was trying to do this using nhibernate:

```
IQuery query = Session.GetNamedQuery("Package1.GetUserInfo");
query.SetParameter("sessionID", sessionId);
```

It returned: Named query not known....

Was searching forums but it seems nhiberate only handle SP on its own, not inside a package.

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried prefixing the package with the schema name?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared a named query called "Package1.GetUserInfo" in your mapping file?

It seems to me that you are confusing the name of the query (assuming it's mapped) with the name of the package method (SP).

Comment: Thanks for reply. There is no mapping (not sure if it needs mapping for exe SP. If so, can you gimme an example? I'm working with .NET c#... if mapping is needed, I really don't see much example online... hope there is an example from you guys...

Comment: If there is no mapping, NHibernate knows nothing about  "Package1.GetUserInfo". I suggest that you read the docs first (http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html)